# append match to new list and delete match from original list

Tags: python

Lets say I have a bunch of strings in a list called "main". How do I iterate through "main and if I find a match, then I delete the matched part in "main" and then add the matched text to a new list called "new"?

python

```
main = ['text \fc + \fr this is my match1 \fc* text', 'text \fc + \fr this is my match2 \fc* text', 'text', 'text', 'text \fc + \fr this is my match \fc* text']
new = []

def rematch(pattern, inp):
  matcher = re.compile(pattern)
  matches = matcher.match(inp)
  if matches:
    new.append(matches)
    #remove match from "main" somehow?

for x in main:
  for m in rematch('\\fc \+ \\fr(.*?)\\fc\*', x):
```

result:

```
main = ['text text', 'text text', 'text', 'text', 'text text']

new = ['this is my match1', 'this is my match2', 'this is my match3']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [33]: import re

In [34]: pat = re.compile('\\fc \+ \\fr(.*?)\\fc\*')

In [43]: main, new = zip(*[(''.join(parts[::2]), ''.join(parts[1::2])) for parts in [pat.split(m) for m in main]])

In [44]: new = [n.strip() for n in new if n]

In [45]: main
Out[45]: ('text  text', 'text  text', 'text', 'text', 'text  text')

In [46]: new
Out[46]: ['this is my match1', 'this is my match2', 'this is my match']
```

---

Explanation:

Notice what happens when you use `pat.split`:

```
In [37]: pat.split(main[0])
Out[37]: ['text ', ' this is my match1 ', ' text']
```

This is similar to what you want except that you want the odd terms in `main` and the even terms in `new`. We'll get to that in a second.

First, let's apply `pat.split` to each of the items in `main`:

```
In [51]: [pat.split(m) for m in main]
Out[51]: 
[['text ', ' this is my match1 ', ' text'],
 ['text ', ' this is my match2 ', ' text'],
 ['text'],
 ['text'],
 ['text ', ' this is my match ', ' text']]
```

Next, let's separate the odd items from the even items, and use `''.join` to smush the items together into one string:

```
In [52]: [(''.join(parts[::2]), ''.join(parts[1::2])) for parts in [pat.split(m) for m in main]]
Out[52]: 
[('text  text', ' this is my match1 '),
 ('text  text', ' this is my match2 '),
 ('text', ''),
 ('text', ''),
 ('text  text', ' this is my match ')]
```

From here, we can use `zip(*...)` to separate `main` from `new`:

```
In [53]: main, new = zip(*[(''.join(parts[::2]), ''.join(parts[1::2])) for parts in [pat.split(m) for m in main]])

In [54]: main
Out[54]: ('text  text', 'text  text', 'text', 'text', 'text  text')

In [55]: new
Out[55]: (' this is my match1 ', ' this is my match2 ', '', '', ' this is my match ')
```

Comment: is there a way to do multiple pattern matches?

Comment: I don't follow you. Can you elaborate on what you are looking for? An example perhaps?

Comment: I figured it out, I appreciate this elaborate and beautiful solution :)